An irreducible topological space with no generic points
I'd like to find an irreducible space with no generic points.
I'm leaning towards this example:
Consider the space $X=(0,1)$ with open sets: $\emptyset$, $X$ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_n=(0,\frac{1}{n})$.
Every non-empty open set intersects, but there isn't a common point in every intersection.
Is this example valid?

Your proposed collection of open subsets of $X = (0, 1)$ is easily checked to be closed under unions and finite intersections and so is a topology. Moreover, any two non-empty open sets have a a non-empty intersection, so your topology is irreducible. For any $x \in X$, there is an $n \in \Bbb{N}_{>0}$ such that $1/n < x$ and then $x$ is contained in the closed set $[1/n, 1)$ and so the closure of $x$ is not the whole of $X$, i.e., $x$ is not a generic point. So, yes, your example is a valid example of an irreducible topological space with no generic points.

Another example is the cofinite topology on an infinite set.  It is $T_1$, hence every point is closed and there is no generic point.  It is also irreducible (= hyperconnected) as any two nonempty open sets intersect.
For other examples, see π-Base, Search for Hyperconnected + T1 + Has multiple points
