Is the generic point of an irreducible sober topological space an isolated point?
Some definitions first.  Let $X$ be a topological space.

$X$ is hyperconnected (also called irreducible) if every open set is dense; i.e., $X$ is not the union of two proper closed subsets.
$X$ is sober if every nonempty irreducible closed subspace $Y\subseteq X$ has a unique generic point (= a point $p\in Y$ that is dense in $Y$; i.e., such that $Y$ is the closure of $\{p\}$; i.e., $p$ is contained in every nonempty open set of $Y$).

Question: If $X$ is a nonempty hyperconnected sober space, it has a unique generic point. Is that point isolated in general?

I can see this is true for finite spaces.  Also more generally for a space with an Alexandrov topology.
Reason: Let $p$ be the generic point of $X$.  Every sober space is $T_0$. If $q\in X$ is different from $p$, there is an open set containing one of the two points and not the other.  But every nonempty open set contains $p$.  So there is an open set containing $p$ and not $q$.  In an Alexandrov space, any intersection of open sets is open.  So $\{p\}$ is open in $X$; that is, $p$ is an isolated point.
So to summarize the argument above:

A generic point in a $T_0$ Alexandrov space is an isolated point.

But I am not sure in the general case.

This is my attempt of counterexample, correct me if I am wrong.
Let $X = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$. Define the topology on $X$ as $\tau = \{ \emptyset, X \} \cup \{[0, \frac{1}{n}[ : n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$, where the intervals are the usual intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ restricted to $X$.
$0$ is an element of every non-empty open set of $X$, hence $X$ has a generic point, and $X$ is hyperconnected.
Let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct points of $X$. Defining $I = [0, \max\{x, y\}[$ (the usual interval of $\mathbb{R}$ restricted to $X$), we have that $\min\{x, y\} \in I$ and $\max\{x, y\} \notin I$. Hence, $X$ is $T_0$.
Let $C$ be a proper non-empty closed subset of $X$, then there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that $C = [\frac{1}{n}, 1]$ (the usual interval of $\mathbb{R}$ restricted to $X$). Let $A$ be an open set of $X$ such that $A \cap C \neq \emptyset$. Let $x \in A \cap C$, then for each $y \in C : y \leq x$, we have that $y \in A$. Therefore, as $\frac{1}{n} = \min{C}$, $\frac{1}{n} \in A$. Hence, $\frac{1}{n}$ is a generic point of $C$ with the subspace topology. We conclude that $X$ is quasi-sober.
As $X$ is $T_0$ and quasi-sober, then $X$ is sober.
$0$ is the unique generic point of $X$. However, by the definition of this space, $0$ is not isolated in $X$, i.e., $X$ has no isolated points.

I believe this generalizes to work for the right ray topology on the successor of any limit ordinal, in particular this is the right ray topology on $\omega+1$.

Or more generally, the right ray topology on any linear order with a non isolated greatest point (equivalently, left ray topology with a non isolated least point, as we have here).

Yeah, you're right!

Actually I may be overlooking some subtleties: consider $[0,1)\cup(2,3)$ with the left ray topology - $(2,3)$ is closed hyperconnected subspace, but lacks a generic point (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4903214/an-irreducible-topological-space-with-no-generic-points). But mumble somthing about existence of infimums and we can fix something up I think...

Instructive example.

Thanks, Patrick!
